# React-testing library: test router redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, react-testing-library

How do I test that the router link changed after a redirect?

After clicking on a button, it should redirect to another page with url ending in "new_page".

This is what I tried, but I keep getting undefined.

```
  {getByTestId} = render(<MyButton />);      

  const mockBoxIconButton = getByTestId('box-icon-button');

  mockBoxIconButton.click();

  console.log(getByTestId('box-icon-button').closest('a')); # undefined
  console.log(getByTestId('box-icon-button').location.href);  # undefined

  expect(
    mockExtractionButton.getByTestId('box-icon-button').closest('a')
  ).toHaveAttribute('href', /http[a-zA-Z0-9:\/-]*new_page/);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim of `react-testing-library` is not to test code implementation but rather testing how a user would perceive UI interactions. So in your case, I would suggest to not look for `/new_page` path after routing. Instead test what the user would interact with after redirecting to the page. It could be another button interaction or readable data inside heading, paragraph or span tags (whatever your most important interaction feels like).

Please refer the following article for more clarity on this:-

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/introducing-the-react-testing-library